# How can I view the subject of an email when replying in Yahoo Mail?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I clicked reply and am typing an email, and it just shows the from and the to, but no subject. How can I view the subject?

(I'm on a slow laptop and have lots of tabs, and I’m not that keen on more with Yahoo Mail, so while I know I could open a new tab log in again if necessary and click inbox, I'd rather have a quicker way like choosing some option to view the subject while I continue to write the email in the browser; I'm wondering if there is such an option.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. While replying, click on the arrow on the left of the “To” field;
   [image]
2. From the drop-down menu, click on **Edit Subject**;
   [image]
3. The *Subject* field will appear below the “To” field.
   [image]